# Brightness is reset to maximum on every restart

Tags: brightness

The brightness of my laptop is reset to max on every restart. I tried the solution provided at [this website](http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-save-screen-brightness-settings-in-ubuntu-12-04-laptop/) but had no luck.

This command

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
```

Returns

```
cat: /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness: No such file or directory
```

Then I found that I don't have a folder named `acpi_video0`, but a folder called `intel_backlight`:

[image: screenshot of /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight in Nautilus]

Every time I increase or decrease the brightness using the brightness control keys, the values in `brightness` and `actual_brightness` get updated.

Is there any method I could follow to set the brightness to a fixed value on every boot and vary it as and when I need it using the brightness control keys?

Comment: I just tried this http://askubuntu.com/questions/145314/how-to-save-brightness-settings ... It doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of: [How do I set default display brightness?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66751/how-do-i-set-default-display-brightness)

Comment: This is happening to me still in version 14. It would be great if this were fixed.

Comment: This solution from Webupd8 works best for me. http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/fix-brightness-getting-reset-to-very.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set default display brightness?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66751/how-do-i-set-default-display-brightness)

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You could try adding a line to /etc/rc.local that will set the desired brightness level. To edit the file, run

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/rc.local
```

and add the following

```
echo X > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

so that the end result looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

echo X > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

exit 0
```

Substitute `X` by the desired brightness level.

In case /etc/rc.local doesn't exist, as is the case with new Ubuntu releases, you'll need to create it, and make eecutable with the following commands:

```
printf '%s\n' '#!/bin/bash' 'exit 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/rc.local
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

PS: Alternatively, there may be `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` instead of the above. Brightness levels vary wildly, and may range from 0 to 10 or to 1000. To find the maximum value, try

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
or
cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness
```

Comment: I just want to understand things around here. This change, is it because I have Intel HD3000 graphics ??

Comment: Probably. Different computers will have different entries in `/sys/class/backlight/`, and figuring out the right location, basically, solved the problem.

Comment: `X` is the desired brightness level on a scale of `0-10` or `0-100`?

Comment: Depends. Different models have different scales. I only had to deal with 0-7. Check the current level by running cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness. It's a good idea to experiment with several values, if you aren't sure which one is right.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in 12.04?

Comment: better solution this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66751/how-do-i-set-default-display-brightness

Comment: mine scales from `0-937`

Comment: After fighting with this issue over several nights, this saves my life.

Comment: Mine goes from 287 to 4882. How oddly specific.

Comment: I have `rc0.d` ~ `rc5.d` in `/etc`, could anyone tell me which directory I should put this script into?

Comment: HP 250 G6, Intel Backlight, scales from `0 - 7125`

Comment: It would be cleaner to install `sysfsutils` and append an entry `class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness = 100` (or whatever your preferred brightness value is) to `/etc/sysfs.conf`.

Comment: Different computers can have different hardware due to which you should check `/sys/class/backlight/` directory for your hardware.
For me `/sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/actual_brightness` worked!

Comment: No `rc.local` in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: When I navigated to sys/class/backlight I m getting 2 directories with Soft Links pointing to some other files as follows :

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  7 12:13 amdgpu_bl0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.0/backlight/amdgpu_bl0

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  7 12:13 nvidia_wmi_ec_backlight -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/PNP0C14:00/wmi_bus/wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00/603E9613-EF25-4338-A3D0-C46177516DB7/backlight/nvidia_wmi_ec_backlight

Both folders have actual_brightness and max_brighness values. Not sure which one to edit

Comment: @user76170 That's a tricky one. Do you have both AMD and Nvidia GPUs? Which one is in use? I'd try AMD first.

Comment: created a /etc/rc.local new file using sudo and wrote this : echo 150 > /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness (trying this with AMD first). When I saved and restarted Ubuntu, the brightness level hadn't reduced. Then I checked the values by navigating to folder /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0. and tried checking brightness using vim brightness. It displays 255. and beneath shows file is read-only.

Answer (score 25):

I converted my small script for saving and restoring backlight (brightness) level to Ubuntu package. It is located in [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Enrbrtx/+archive/ubuntu/sysvinit-backlight) and named `sysvinit-backlight`.
It contains sysvinit init-script, placed in `/etc/init.d/sysvinit-backlight`.
It is compatible with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and 14.04 LTS.

For newer versions of Ubuntu my PPA is not needed as they use builtin systemd-backlight service.

You can install my script with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nrbrtx/sysvinit-backlight
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sysvinit-backlight
```

You can remove it by

```
sudo apt-get purge sysvinit-backlight
```

Please note: if you have installed the previous version of my script, please remove it by

```
sudo rm /etc/rc?.d/?25backlight /etc/init.d/brightness /etc/rc?.d/?25brightness
```

The script functionality is:

- save backlight (brightness) levels of all video adapters and keyboard on reboot and shutdown (runlevel 0 and 6)
- load backlight (brightness) levels for all video adapters and keyboard  on boot (runlevels S, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5)

The script options are:

- `sudo service sysvinit-backlight status` (show current brightness levels and saved in files values)
- `sudo service sysvinit-backlight start` (set saved levels from files)
- `sudo service sysvinit-backlight stop` (save current levels to files)

You can contact me here or on launchpad.

Comment: I reported a bug about including such initscript to default Ubuntu installation - http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1270579.

Comment: Works perfectly for my Dell laptop on Ubuntu 14.04. As the laptop has a on-chip graphics adapter plus another adapter (that is used by default), I just had to change `/acpi_video0/` to `/acpi_video1/`.

Comment: This script is practical.  Worked for me too on my lenovo flex 2. I think it should also be included in default Ubuntu or Linux mint installs.

Comment: This script no longer works in 16.04+

Comment: *answerSeeker*
This script should not work in 16.04+, it is unneeded here. Use standard systemd-backlight@.service.

Comment: @N0rbert there's `systemd-backlight@backlight:` in 20.04 but inactive (dead)

Answer (score 24):

Easiest way:

1. Open a terminal window.
2. Type in the following command then hit Enter after it.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xbacklight
   ```
3. Open the **Startup Applications** Preferences menu.
4. Click the Add button and add the following information:

   - Name: Brightness
   - Command: `xbacklight -set 60`
5. Replace 60 with whatever brightness level you prefer.

Source: [Set Startup Display Brightness](http://desktoplinuxreviews.com/linux-tips/linux-mint-tips/how-to-set-startup-display-brightness-in-linux-mint-14/)

Comment: thank you, it works perfectly for me. Ubuntu 14.04 on Acer 5732Z

Comment: It doesn't work on ubuntu 16.10

Comment: Does not work ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Worked for me, Ubuntu 18.04 - NVIDIA Drivers installed (430.26) - considering that I was already able to edit brightness manually with Fn keys in laptop - I just needed to set a default value for them on startup

Comment: Doesn't work in 20.04 (hp envy)

Answer (score 14):

Before try workarounds in `rc.local`, it is worth to try the following:

- adding simple: `quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor` to grub looks to be enough on my configuration.

  1. `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
  2. replace
     `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
     with
     `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset acpi_backlight=vendor"`
  3. `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

worked on:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Asus U31SD-XH51 )
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Dell 14z)
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Lenovo g500, remove `nomodeset` and it will work fine)

Comment: more details http://www.ubuntuka.com/ubuntu-command-line-tricks-set-1/: `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and replace `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Comment: Unfortunately it breaks the brightness adjustment from the fn keys on 14.04.

Comment: works for me as well on 14.04 ... fn keys for brightess were not working also previously so ...

Comment: This seemed to work fine - for one reboot (even the Fn keys on my Dell laptop worked). But after another reboot the Fn keys brightness did not affect the screen any more. And worse: The wakeup after standby (suspend to RAM) stopped working with a dark screen.

Comment: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset acpi_backlight=vendor" works for me

Comment: Doesnt work in Ubuntu 22.04. Brightness gets resetted to maximum on restart. I have a Dell G15 Ryzen Edition Laptop

Answer (score 6):

I modified the code in `/etc/rc.local` like this:

Get maximum brightness:

```
$ cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness
4882
```

Run `gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local` and edit the file:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

echo 4882 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
exit 0
```

That worked for me.

Comment: I don't get it, what would that do? It's already maximum by default.

Comment: You should use `cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
168` instead. I use 168 because my eyes don't hurt at that brightness level

Answer (score 6):

Install xbacklight (`sudo apt-get install xbacklight`) and add

```
xbacklight -set x
```

(where 'x' = 0 to 100 desired brightness) to the startup applications via dashboard. For example:

```
xbacklight -set 50
```

Comment: And how does this fix the 'reset on reboot' issue in the question?

Comment: this adjust the brightness just for current session. if you restart then the brightness is reset.

Comment: Not if you add it to startup applications. And yes this is a work-around, not a full resolution.

Comment: Brightness is reset like other solutions but `Add`ding this to `Startup Applications Preferences` works for me.

Answer (score 4):

The solutions offered here are somehow system-dependent.

A good design is to have one place that takes care of system-dependent details and provide a unified interface. It seems that currently the kernel does not offer such an easy interface through `/sys`. At X level, though, there is one : `xbacklight`.

A solution based on `xbacklight` is offered on [How do I set default display brightness?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66751/how-do-i-set-default-display-brightness/232668#232668), for 11.10 and up.

Plus, it should not have the problems reported on some areas (e.g. http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-save-screen-brightness-settings-in-ubuntu-12-04-laptop ) that wrong brightness comes back in some situations.

Answer (score 3):

How to debug backlighting:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight

Unfortunately just adding acpi_backlight=vendor doesn't seem to save the default value for my 12.04 Lenovo G575.

Answer (score 2):

I use a Sony Vaio S model and hybrid graphics. I disabled my ATI G card and so my intel HD 3000 serves as my only g card.

I found that setting the brightness value to the file `actual_brightness` in the `intel_backlight` folder will help. and the other wont.

for me my minimum brightness value is 236 and maximum is 4648, so you may set a value anywhere between this.

so try this:

```
echo 236 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness
```

Answer (score 2):

My laptop is Compaq Presario CQ62 111TU, installed Ubuntu 12.04. The Following steps worked for me well.

1. Adjust the screen brightness to your preferred level.
2. Open Terminal and enter `cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness` and take down the value.
3. Enter `cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/actual_brightness` and take down the value.
4. Enter `sudo gedit /etc/rc.local` and add these before the last line `exit 0` in gedit:

   ```
   echo ValueFromStep2 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
   echo ValueFromStep3 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
   ```

save and enjoy.

**My settings are shown below**

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

echo 478 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness

exit 0
```

Comment: This worked great for me. All I needed was the /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness line.

Answer (score 2):

I find N0rbert's solution to be the best one, as the script that he's provided allows to restore your previous brightness level on startup.

Although, there was a small modification that I had to introduce to his solution to make it work. Instead of creating symbolic links that he's mentioned, I've provided the following:

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/brightness /etc/rc0.d/S25backlight
ln -s /etc/init.d/brightness /etc/rc2.d/S25backlight
ln -s /etc/init.d/brightness /etc/rc6.d/S25backlight
```

Notice, that instead of `rcS.d`, I've added a symbolic link to `rc2.d`, which is a runlevel for "Graphical multi-user with networking" ([see more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel#Ubuntu)). I believe that the reason why the former one doesn't work for me is Ubuntu overriding brightness level after it has been set up by the `/etc/init.d/brightness` script during `S` runlevel.

With that subtle change, restoring brightness level works like a charm, especially for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on Lenovo ThinkPad L540.

Answer (score 1):

No need to fall into scripting and coding.

Just follow these simple steps:

If screen brightness is stuck at maximum every startup, install xbacklight (`sudo apt-get install xbacklight`) and add "xbacklight -set x" (where 'x' = 0 to 100 desired brightness) to the startup applications via dashboard. For example, "xbacklight -set 50".

I have set brightness for my laptop to 30.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbookPrime
[Search for word "brightness" and read related paragraphs on this source page.]

Enjoy!!

Answer (score 1):

I added the following into /etc/rc.local, to manage the display brightness and keyboard backlit and it works perfectly

```
...
echo 30 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
echo 3 | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/applesmc.768/leds/smc::kbd_backlight/brightness

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to discover your current brightness level:

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Then, edit rc.local file using this command:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Add this line before `exit 0` line:

```
echo X > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

If this don't solve the problem, can be that something in your system is overwriting the brightness level. Then, you can try add a sleep command to delay the execution of the previous command:

```
(sleep 10 && echo X > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness)
```

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1976157&p=11924240#post11924240)

Answer (score 1):

This works on ubuntu 16.10

Create a file `brightness.service` in `/lib/systemd/system` with the following contents(Change 100 to whatever brightness you want, roughly it's between 0 ~ 1000).

```
[Unit]
Description=Lower default brightness

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/zsh -c "echo 100 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable it.

```
sudo systemctl enable brightness.
```

Restart. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

It is well worth checking the max_brightness files for the absolute maximum values in /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight and /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0 directories to avoid setting unusable values.

My Dell Inspiron 5720 uses maximum values of 4882 and 100 respectively.  I have set these to 2508 and 52 to prolong battery life. ACPI value in this case is equivalent to the percentage of the maximum brightness.

Editing rc.local works for me. I added comments to clarify how the values were determined. set required brightness with function keys and read values in brightness or actual_brightness files in each of the above Intel / ACPI directories.

Answer (score 0):

For mint mate 17, you can set the default brightness by following steps:

- sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
- Applications -> System Tools -> dconf tools,
- search for backlight, find and change following options:

  - brightness-ac 
    brightness when use AC powser (charged),
  - brightness-dim-battery 
    brightness when use battery (not charged),

Answer (score 0):

all replies are helpful but didnt help me what i was trying to achieve. i wanted pre-defined levels of brightness for battery and ac power.

1. use laptop mode tools from here [laptop mode tools](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/install-laptop-mode-tools-164-with.html)
2. edit the conf file for brightness and replace [values] with the values you want. like "echo 1" for battery.[wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Laptop_Mode_Tools)

works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

This is yet another workaround

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/tty of=/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
3000
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

less typing for fumble fingers...

Answer (score 0):

**Change default brightness level in Ubuntu 14. 04 LTS / Brightness is reset to Maximum on every Restart on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**

Here is what i found out.

In my case I had both the folders.

And when I changed the default brightness level, it took the change from the file in the folder **acpi_video0**. i.e. from the second line of code.

***Here is the code that will be helpful for setting the default brightness level for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.***

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#rc.local
#This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
#Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
#Value on error.
#In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
#bits.
#By default this script does nothing.
#
#
#
#if you are changing the default brightness in Ubuntu 14.4 LTS
#the brightness under the folder acpi_video0 is important.
#Because brightness is set from that folder and not from intel_backlight
#(in case of my PC. It may very in others)
#That means you can omit the first echo line.
#However the command lines are given if any one has some problem and doesnot
#have the acpi_video0 folder
echo 1020 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
#Under the above given address the range of brightness is from 0 to 4648.
echo 3 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
#Under the above given address the range of brightness is from 0 to 7.
exit 0
```