# Auto-change in brightness after reboot Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, brightness

I have noticed that after I set the brightness (High to Low) in Ubuntu 13.10 and then after when I do my work. After rebooting up the PC, the brightness again turns to High. I'm literally tired of this. :'( :(

Comment: My problem is reverse, It's going to low with both ubuntu 13.04 and Ubuntu 13.10.Why there is no fix for that?

Answer (score 0):

you should have a look at this thread:

[Brightness is reset to Maximum on every Restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151651/brightness-is-reset-to-maximum-on-every-restart)

i used the following in a startup script, but that's on an imac:
echo 8 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness

again, have a look at the thread above.  lots of advice, something should work for you.