# Unable to adjust brightness on a Sony Vaio

Tags: 13.10

I am having a *Sony Vaio SVE1513BYN*.  I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 . Once I set brightness of my laptop and then after I restart my laptop it is changed. Brightness is going full as default.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file /etc/default/grub. 
You can do this by going to the terminal and typing:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

and then save and then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then restart the computer, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a line to /etc/rc.local that will set the desired brightness level. To edit the file, run

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

and add the following

```
echo X > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

so that the end result looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

echo X > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

exit 0
```

Substitute the `X` by the desired brightness level.

source:[Brightness is reset to Maximum on every Restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151651/brightness-is-reset-to-maximum-on-every-restart)