# The brightness of my laptop reset every reboot?

Tags: brightness

How to save the brightness in my laptop , so every reboot will stay the same and not changed .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Brightness is reset to Maximum on every Restart](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151651/brightness-is-reset-to-maximum-on-every-restart)

Answer (score 0):

edit /etc/rc.local to insert your preffered value:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

and add the following

```
echo X > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

replace X by the value of your need