# Ubuntu boots up with full brightness

Tags: boot, brightness

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 in my samsung laptop,everytime i boot up the system it starts with full screen brightness which is quite annoying in the night.

Is there a way to fix this problem so that the brightness remains at a level which i set before shutting down the system ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/151651/brightness-is-reset-to-maximum-on-every-restart

check this link...this might help..

Answer (score 1):

I am having this same issue, but I am using 14.04. Were you able to find a solution? I noticed this was posted a few weeks ago. I have a Samsung ATIV Book 8 with an Intel 4000 video card and a AMD Radeon 8700M hybrid graphics. Not sure if the open source drivers has anything to do with this or the cause of it.