# Brightness Save on Reboot

Tags: permissions, brightness, 14.04, backlight, etc

I have a problem where the brightness does not save after a reboot on 14.04 LTS, but I had the same problem on 12.04 LTS (before I broke the system).  Before you say this is a duplicate of a million posts, I've tried every single option that has been mentioned.  I've found that `xbacklght` doesn't work no mater what I do with it. On my edited `/etc/rc.local`, however, I've set it to execute, changed the permissions so it would run without `sudo` and even changed the permissions of the `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` files (and yes I've tried the actual folder as well, not just the sym link).  I got it to work a few times, but only for one boot until the permission changes reset themselves.  Thanks for the help in advance!

**EDIT:** I just remeber that I also have a folder called `intel_brightness` with it's own set of values that could affect how `acpi_video0` works.  Sorry for forgetting to add this earlier

Comment: Can you include your `/etc/rc.local` file in your question, and include some of the relevant posts that you have looked at. http://askubuntu.com/questions/151651/brightness-is-reset-to-maximum-on-every-restart

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to add my `rc.local` file but the value I added was `echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`.  I've looked at every relevant post I could find.  Look at the "Related" sidebar and chose one. @jmunsch

Comment: I should have said "can you include the contents of" instead of "can you include the file". Copy and paste the contents of `/etc/rc.local` it into your question by editing. This would be very helpful as well. Thanks.

Comment: @jmunsch I'm not at my compute now, so I can't give you the contents, but I've memorized it.  (Whole bunch of commented out lines which are there by default) `echo > 5 /sys/class/acpi_video0/brightness` than a new line `exit 0` and that's it.  Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

- Edit `/etc/rc.local`

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
  ```
- Before `exit 0` insert this line

  ```
  sh -c "echo  10 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness"
  ```

This will set your screen brightness to 10/15 during startup. You can replace 10 with any integer from 0 to 15. You can save somewhere brightness value just before reboot, then you need to include a command to read the previously saved value from a file and use that value instead of 10 (in above example) to set the brightness value.

Also you can get current brightness by

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I already added that line, which sadly never worked, leading me to ask the question here.  I tried to add the '/etc/rc.local' file on my question, but I couldn't figure out how on this site.

Comment: if you add these lines in terminal `sudo sh -c "echo  10 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness"` then does it work?

Comment: Yes.  '/etc/rc.local' works fine as well as long as you run it as root, but I can't do that with start-up, and it doesn't seem to run the way it should by running itself as root at boot