# Brightness Resets on Boot/Reboot in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, nvidia, 14.04, brightness

As the question statement explains itself, I'm on Ubuntu **14.04** and my screen brightness is reset to **maximum** after every boot, no matter how many times I reset.

I applied the solution provided here [Brightness is reset to Maximum on every Restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151651/brightness-is-reset-to-maximum-on-every-restart?rq=1)
But once, & it resulted into corrupting my Ubuntu Installation, I had to re-install my Ubuntu copy. Now I'm reluctant to try that again.

***I need a safer method to set this problem straight.***

Hardware:
Laptop - **HP Pavilion DV6 -7071tx**

Screen Res - **1080p Full HD**

Graphics - **Nvidia GT650M**

Ubuntu - Dual boot & Installed on **32Gb - SSD**

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal and type `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` . A window will pop out, and add `echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` before the last line “`exit 0`″. Number `5` is the value of your screen brightness. With `cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness` command you can check the maximum. This might work for you, Have fun.

Comment: That didn't solve it.
But I just updated Ubuntu using Software Center (80Mb+) and it has solved my problem. The brightness state is saved on shutdown and recovered on restart dynamically. Just what I wanted. Thanks for help btw.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still having this problem what I did to solve it in ubuntu 18.04 is:

`printf '#!/bin/bash\n\necho 20 > /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/brightness' | sudo tee /etc/rc.local && sudo chmod 744 /etc/rc.local`

(Change 20 for any number that you desire between 0-100)

The brightness level is on `/sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/brightness` so changing the value that's in there, it will automatically modify the current screen brightness.