# Brightness is reset to maximum after waking up from suspend or lock screen

Tags: laptop, suspend, brightness

This question is somewhat related to this question: [Brightness is reset to Maximum on every Restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151651/brightness-is-reset-to-maximum-on-every-restart)

Basically, I modified `/etc/rc.local` to set the brightness, as detailed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/151665/81011), so on startup the brightness does get set to the correct value.  However, when I suspend my laptop and wake it up, or simply close the screen and reopen it, the brightness gets reset to the maximum.

My machine runs Ubuntu 14.04 + Gnome 3.  The machine is a Thinkpad X1 Carbon.

What's the solution?

Answer (score 4):

For waking up from suspension, I create the following script `/etc/pm/sleep.d/brightness`:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
    resume|thaw)
        echo 170 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
        ;;
esac
```

And the permission of the script is `-rwxr-xr-x`. This should also solve your problem.

But if the screen is dimmed, the brightness is set to maximum after recovering from the dimming.

This is really a bug which should be fixed.

I am using ubuntu 64 bit 14.04 with a Thinkpad T440s.

Comment: Clarify my answer according to your suggestion.