# Unable to change brightness using after root access

Tags: 14.04, bash, permissions, brightness

**Case-1**
Recently I read a question([Brightness is reset to Maximum on every Restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151651/brightness-is-reset-to-maximum-on-every-restart)). Then I opened up my terminal and typed out following command-

```
sudo echo 200 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
bash: /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness: Permission denied
```

Since I am using this in root, this command should replace my value. Why value is not being replaced by new one?

**Case-2**
 On folder /sys/class/backlight there is another folder acpi_video0, there is file named brightness, should I need to do something in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal output redirection operator is always executed with your user privileges, also when you write a sudo in front of the command which generates the STDOUT text. In other words, this will fail if you dont have the permission to write to that file

So `sudo echo` won't work even when you are using sudo,

you should use `tee` in this scenario like below

`echo 200 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

Comment: Thank You very much, not only you gave me solution of my problem but also told me logic behind all these, now I understood.

Comment: @aVIRA or you can use `sudo su -c "echo 200 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"`