# boot with e4rat suddenly takes 20sec longer

Tags: 14.04, boot, time, bootchart

A couple of days ago I set-up e4rat for my Ubuntu 14.04 running on a Lenovo Ideapad U330. The first couple of days it really did wonders, basically cutting the boot-time from 50sec to 25sec.

Then all of a sudden, for no (obvious) reasons it took 20sec longer again. The change actually happened from a boot at ~1am compared to a boot the next morning ~9am. Ever since, it's been stuck at the 45sec mark.

I tried to look at my boot-charts and you can actually see that before e4rat-preload started at ~5secs in the boot-process and now it starts at ~25secs. The strange thing is: from 5 until 25secs there is nothing at all happening, at least according to the bootchart.
In the boot process e4rat-preload is taking incredibly much time now at the point where it says `loading I-Nodes`. That part was a lot faster before.

If anyone has any idea on how to fix this, I'd be more than happy. 
Thanks in advance for your effort.!

Here are the before/after bootcharts. I cut them a little, to show the important part in the beginning. Apart from that, they look very much similar. If it helps I can of course add the whole charts. (obs: it really was the same day, without any major updates etc.)

[image: before bootchart]

[image: after bootchart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out myself now.

Actually (of course) there had been something I changed between those two boot events. 
Trying to make my laptop boot to low screen brightness by default, I used the following answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/151665/261197).

In a nutshell: I updated my

```
/etc/rc.local
```

file, in a way that it would run

```
echo X > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

in the boot process. (click [here](http://wiki.vpslink.com/Linux_File_Reference:_/etc/rc.local) for more info on rc.local)

I don't really understand why, but it is apparently interfering strongly with e4rat-preload.

Taking away this statement I end up at ~25sec boot time again.

Hope this will be of help for similar problems.

Comment: how did you find out that indeed rc.local is interfering ?