# Brightness level resets itself back to full brightness after every reboot

Tags: brightness

I can easily adjust the level of brightness with the function keys while I'm actively working in the OS, but it resets itself back to full brightness after every reboot which, of course, is something I don't want. I would like to be able to have my latest adjustments automatically saved for me so that I don't have to tinker with them every time I boot up my PC.

Version of **Ubuntu** installed is **14.04.3 LTS**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Brightness is reset to Maximum on every Restart](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151651/brightness-is-reset-to-maximum-on-every-restart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using **xbacklight**

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

Then you can check current brightnes by `xbacklight -get` and set it by `xbacklight -set xx` where xx is percent...
To make it permanent you can make a startup script. here is a great guide how to do so: [How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)

Comment: So, basically that program doesn't really solve the problem, but is just a command-line way of what I already can do with the function keys responsible for the brightness of the display? And to make it remember what it was set to, I need to automatically run a script at boot-up time? Do I understand everything correctly? Is this the only way to solve the problem?

Comment: 1. Yes, you'r correct. 2. I don't know, maybe there is some native Gnome-side way to do the trick, I've only shared solution that works for me...

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll look into that a bit later. But this sounds more like a hack though.

Comment: I too am having this issue in Ubuntu 20.04. I'm looking for a native solution.