# Brightness goes to max after every boot ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, brightness

I can control the brightness when i'm working on the OS but during startup it always resets to maximum brightness. Can anyone please provide me with a solution so that my past brightness preference is automatically saved for next boot. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on Acer swift 3, Ryzen 5 varient

EDIT : Output for sudo lshw -class display

*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: Renoir
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
version: c3
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
resources: irq:47 memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c01fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:c0600000-c067ffff

Comment: I think this answer is well explained to solve your problem : <br>
[Brightness reset to maximum after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/a/151665/1266038)

Comment: @1nfern0 that will depend on the graphical card in use. We do not have that information. Add the output of `sudo lshw -class display` to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is what I did.

To find current brightness level:

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness
```

Set the brightness on boot using:

```
echo 30 > /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness
```

Comment: It says permission denied for me.....dunno what to do .....if u know pls do let me know .....thanks for answering anyways!!

Comment: use "sudo su" to login as root and execute.

Comment: tried it....still didn't work :(