# Full brightness on startup after the recent update

Tags: 20.04, gnome, startup, brightness, reboot

After every reboot, my laptop, on startup is on with 100% brightness. I have to manually turn it down using the function keys everytime. Generally, the default start-up brightness used to be around 20% which too I had used to turn down, but now after a recent update it has reached to 100% on its own.

My other laptop running the same version is still at 20% default start-up brightness. I know there can be user made scripts that will automatically turn down the brightness for me on each start-up. But I want to do this natively and permanently from system settings or something.

I'm running **Ubuntu 20.04** on Dell 5559 laptop.

Comment: It appears to be a known bug:
https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5994645.html

Comment: See also [Brightness is reset to maximum on every restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151651/brightness-is-reset-to-maximum-on-every-restart)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that there's a process that runs at boot, and also at shutdown, that tries to restore/save backlight settings. On some configurations the restore happens incorrectly, and can cause the brightness problem that you see. Here we will add a minor kernel option so that this process doesn't restore an invalid brightness setting.

```
man systemd-backlight
```

Rather than using the script that you found, (*that I probably wrote*), do this:

Edit /etc/default/grub:

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

Locate the line that looks like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

And change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash systemd.restore_state=0"
```

`sudo update-grub`

Set your brightness to the desired level.

`reboot`

**Update #1:**

/etc/systemd/system$ more set_brightness.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Set screen brightness to work around bug

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh /etc/rc.local/set_brightness.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/systemd/system$ more /etc/rc.local/set_brightness.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

# Set specific brightness level to work around bug
# See /etc/systemd/system/set_brightness.service
#
sleep 15; echo 80 | tee /sys/class/backlight/dell_uart_backlight/brightness
```

Comment: This did not change a thing. The screen brightness on startup is still full. Now I think my only option is to setup a script to turn down the brightness so that it runs on every startup.

Comment: @VinRaghav See Update #1 in my answer. It's a .service that I run on my system to set brightness to 80. Minor customization will be required.

Comment: @heynnema The update is vague. Doesn't explain what's happening.

Comment: @VinRaghav It's a .service that sets the brightness level to a desired level. I set it to 80 (where mine can go from 1 to 100), your setting might be different. Two parts... a .service file and the .sh script. You just have to tailor it to your specific system... like the path with dell_uart_backlight is not right for your system.

Answer (score 3):

In my case on Ideapad Gaming 3 it was also broken, but I found that `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video1/brightness` has the correct value after a reboot, in the 0-50 range, while `/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness` has a range of 0-255.

So I wrote a small `.deb`, which you can find in the *Releases* section of [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/Intueor/brightness-fix), for restoring and fixing the issue by using the correct ratio at startup. You can customize the installed service for different paths and ratio (see the description for details).