# Brightness resetting to 100% on every startup

Tags: brightness, bug-reporting

This question has been asked many times by many users, but there is no definate answer and it still remains [an open bug](https://askubuntu.com/a/1390673/740334) even after all this time. This appears to be a problem with Ubuntu on some selected number of laptops. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 for almost 2 years now, but this problem arose in last 1 or 2 months. Most solutions I have read online regarding this are to run an automated script to lower the brightness on every startup. But that is not a native solution. I would like a permanent fix to this because this bug didn't exist for me before 1-2 months ago. My other laptop which is also running 20.04 doesn't have this issue. I'm running the latest version of Ubuntu 20.04 on *Dell 5559* laptop with an SSD.

Comment: Both have the same video card and same driver?

Comment: Both are Dell laptops, but have different hardwares. I have mentioned the one that is having the issue.

Comment: You pointed out the other one does not have this issue so yes the hardware differences especially the video card do matter.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Full brightness on startup after the recent update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390422/full-brightness-on-startup-after-the-recent-update)

Comment: See also [Brightness is reset to maximum on every restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151651/brightness-is-reset-to-maximum-on-every-restart)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there's a process that runs at boot, and also at shutdown, that tries to restore/save backlight settings. One some configurations the restore happens incorrectly, and can cause the brightness problem that you see. Here we will add a minor kernel option so that this process doesn't restore an invalid brightness setting.

```
man systemd-backlight
```

Rather than using the script that you found, (*that I probably wrote*), do this:

Edit /etc/default/grub:

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

Locate the line that looks like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

And change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash systemd.restore_state=0"
```

`sudo update-grub`

Set your brightness to the desired level.

`reboot`

Comment: Could you explain what this will do? Will this impact just the brightness state or everything?

Comment: @VinRaghav I updated my answer. It's a harmless mod that only effects the brightness being restored to an incorrect value at boot time.

Comment: This change won't only affect the brightness, but everything.

Comment: @VinRaghav How do you figure? It only effects the backlight restore at boot time. Did you try it?